# Expecting NEWLINE in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, eof

i'm having an error showing :

```
line 1:5 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting NEWLINE
```

for my input :

```
print "hi"
```

I'm basically new to ANTLR so I really don't have any idea on what this error is about? I do get that I should have an End-of-File, but how should I place it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm basically new to ANTLR so I really don't have any idea on what this error is about?

It means the parser stumbles upon the end of the file, while it expects a line break. To fix it, simply place a line break at the end of your input.

This means you have something like this in your grammar:

```
parse : (statement NEWLINE)+ EOF
```

making the `NEWLINE` mandatory just before the `EOF`. You could also do something like this:

```
parse : statement (NEWLINE statement)* NEWLINE* EOF
```

making `NEWLINE` optional at the end, but mandatory between `statement`s.

Comment: would it affect the output of my statement?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. You either need to place a line break in your input string (because you defined it like that in your grammar), or change the grammar itself.